# Convert Objective-C block to Swift block

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c-blocks

I want to convert this Objective-C code to Swift.

```
pieView.layer.transformTitleBlock = ^(PieElement* elem, float percent){
         return [(MyPieElement*)elem title]; 
};
```

I wrote this code in Swift:

```
pieView.layer.transformTitleBlock = {(elem:PieElement!,percent:Float) -> String in
            //your stuff
            return MyPieElement(elem.title);
        }
```

But it isn't working for me; please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? It would be better If you included the exact result/problem you had.

Comment: the below is worked for me thanks (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misinterpreted the cast.

```
[(MyPieElement*)elem title];
```

In Objective-C is equivalent to:

```
(elem as MyPieElement).title
```

in Swift.

Comment: It's only equivalent to the second option. The first option is creating a new object.  The second casts the existing object into a new type.

Comment: You're right. I had added the first option in the event that he was casting a primitive (i.e. `Int`). He obviously isn't, so I removed that.

Answer (score 0):

You should return string value not MyPieElement object.
Try that it works for me:

```
    pieView.layer.transformTitleBlock = {
        elem, percent in
        return elem.title
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of your closure is a `String`, but you're returning an instance of `MyPieElement`. I suspect this is what you want to do:

```
 pieView.layer.transformTitleBlock = {(elem: PieElement!, percent:Float) -> String in
        return elem.title
 }
```